# could not work my second comment box under loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i was create commnent box under loop in every product.but in my first product,i commented here successfully.but in my second product,when i click "Add Comment" then i found and unexpected result.which is after click,this comment was not displayed as like my first product vedio comment.

Here is my code:

```
<h4>Product Review</h4>
</br></br>





@foreach (var laptop in ViewBag.v)
{

    <div class="row">
        <video src="~/@laptop.Image1" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top" controls height="400px" loop />
    </div>
    @:</br>
    @:<div class="border">
        <div id="display" class="ml-2"></div>
    @:</div>
    @:</br>
    @:<div class="comment">
        <textarea id="title" type="text " rows="2" cols="4" onkeyup="Allow()" placeholder="write a comment......" style="width:840px;height:50px;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="insert()" style="width:150px;height:50px;" />
        @:</form>
    @:</div>
    

    <div class="row float-right">
        <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="ShopShow" asp-route-id="@laptop.Id" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-outline-light">Details</a>
    </div>
    @:</br></br></hr>
   


}
```

site.js

```
var titles = [];
var titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");
function Allow() {
    if (!user.title.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && user.title.value != "") {
        user.title.value = "";
        alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
    }
    window.location.reload()
}
function insert() {
    titles.push(titleInput.value);
    clearAndShow();
}
function clearAndShow() {
    titleInput.value = "";
    messageBox.innerHTML = "";
    messageBox.innerHTML += " " + titles.join("<br/> ") + "<br/>";
}
```

Output:

[image]

above output,my first comment box is working but second comment box is not working. what's the solution.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is, but `var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");` will always return the first element matching that ID. I'm guessing that's causing some undesired behavior since you can have multiple elements with that ID on your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your codes, I found you just use `document.getElementById("title")` to get the title element. Since you have multiple input element named title. That means it will always find the first title element.

This is the reason why your textarea value will always add to the first one.

To solve this issue, you could add an index to the textarea id like this:

The i is the index of the ViewBag.v.

Then you could pass the index i as the parameter to the insert javascript function.

Besides, I found you have used title[] as a global variable, this will make all the display div used same textarea value. To solve this issue, I suggest you could remove the title array and directly add the textarea value and remove the textarea.

More details, you could refer to below code sample:

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        ViewBag.v  = new List<Laptop>() { new Laptop { Image1="path1", Id=1 }, new Laptop { Image1="path2" , Id=2} };
        return View();
      
    }
```

View:

```
<h4>Product Review</h4>
</br></br>
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.v.Count; i++)
{

    <div class="row">
        <video src="~/@ViewBag.v[i].Image1" alt="Card Image" class="card-img-top" controls height="400px" loop />
    </div>
    @:</br>
    @:<div class="border">
        <div id="display_@i" class="ml-2"></div>
    @:</div>
    @:</br>
    @:<div class="comment">
        <textarea id="title_@i" type="text " rows="2" cols="4" onkeyup="Allow(@i)" placeholder="write a comment......" style="width:840px;height:50px;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" class="btn btn-outline-dark" 
               onclick="insert(@i)" style="width:150px;height:50px;" />
        @:</form>
    @:</div>
    <div class="row float-right">
        <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="ShopShow" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.v[i].Id" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-outline-light">Details</a>
    </div>
    @:</br></br></hr>
}
```

js:

```
 function Allow() {
    if (!user.title.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && user.title.value != "") {
        user.title.value = "";
        alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
    }
    window.location.reload()
}
function insert(i) {
    var titleInput = document.getElementById("title_" + i);
    var messageBox = document.getElementById("display_" + i);

 
   messageBox.innerHTML +=  titleInput.value + "<br/>";


    titleInput.value = '';
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you put input elements inside a loop, their IDs is duplicated and that is not OK. Javascript can't tell the different between those elements and usually get the first element and ignore all others.

To solve this, you should either change the ID to something like `title_1` and `title_2` so you can reference to them separately.

```
for (index ..) {
    <input id="title_${index}"/>
    <input submit onclick="insert(index)"/>
}

function insert(index) {
    const element = find('title_' + index);
    ....
}
```

Or you can find the element relative to the submit button.

Comment: please clarify your code.i don't understood where i change because of beginner level.

Comment: @Linkon dude, it's pseudo code, you're supposed to understand the idea and implement it on your own.